# Replacing a missing capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I've managed to break off a smd ceramic 1206 capacitor of a motherboard I am working on, I'm am new to electronics, so be gentle! Anyway this damn capacitor has vanished into the place where all missing tiny components seem to go! I cannot find any schematics for the board to see what I need to replace. Good news is I have two boards, I need both, so no I cannot swap it out. So how do I test the capacitor to replace the missing one as there's no markings at all? I have a Multimeter only and it's basic AstroAI AM33D. Any advice would be very helpful! I've attached a photo sorry about the quality the parts are small.

[image: Capacitor missing]

Comment: Your best best will be to remove the capacitor from the second board and measure it there. You can find "smart tweezers" or other tools that can measure capacitance online. You cannot measure it while it is still on the board! Also, don't break off the caps or you will damage the cap and the board.

Comment: you  need its value, from a capacity-meter (multimeter with this function) on the safe board (take it off, mesure, & put it again)

Comment: It looks like it's in parallel with the other 3 SMT capacitors (and maybe the electrolytic) so you might find it works without it (up to a point) then if you get problems, measure the DC voltage across those capacitors and choose a capacitor of the correct voltage rating and take a wild guess at its value (say 100 nF). Then see if any problems that might have happened turn to dust.

Comment: Thanks for the help! great advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all 805 cases.

If I were designing this for best rise time for a 1MHz to 1 GHz Load on current with 4 ceramic caps only, my reasoning follows.

The reason 1 is farther away is to add a few nH isolation with the 3 smaller 0.01 uF caps which have lower ESR and higher frequency response.

The isolated one will be a high quality X7R 0.1uF cap which due to physics and geometry.   There will/may be others near load <100pF.(NPO)

The round can is an e-cap.

Comment: I wondered already why the cap was isolated. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since capacitors are not typically marked, the only way to find the value is to measure them.

You'll have to get a meter that can measure capacitance<sup>1</sup>, take the corresponding capacitor off of the good board, measure its value, and then purchase a replacement that's the same size and value. Solder both capacitors back onto their respective boards.

BTW, even without a scale for measurement, that looks a lot more like 0805 to me than 1206.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are plenty of cheap [LCR tester kits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Br3L1B80ow) on the market that can do this.

Comment: Thanks, it could well be a 0805 and not a 1206 I tried to take its measurements, some seem to sit in between 2-3mm. I will get one of these kits then and go from there.